# How can I hide ActionLinks based on user roles?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorization

In a standard, generated list view, how can I hide certain ActionLinks based on the roles the logged in user belongs to?

Comment: `if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("someRole")) ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend wrote up this [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20200221092700/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/tyarmer/archive/2010/02/25/strongly-typed-roles-in-mvc-with-authorize-attribute.aspx) about supporting multiple roles in security checks without "magic strings".  (He discusses action links at the end.) I also have a comment there. I recommend putting the logic to determine permissions into your view model so that you don't clutter your view with permission checks.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but for now I've just used a magic string as input to an extension method I wrote called 'RoleFilteredActionLink', that returns null if the user is not authorized or calls the normal ActionLink if he is.

Comment: The post is showing some thing hard coded :(. `<%=Html.ActionLinkWithRoles("Home", "Index", "Home", ProjectRoles.Admin, ProjectRoles.User)%>`. I m talking about the last parms.